# Codeigniter Update Data In Database

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, codeigniter-3, insert-update

I'm new to Codeigniter and am having a problem understanding what I did wrong in my code for updating data in my database. I would really appreciate your input, since I have been wrecking my brains trying to figure out the problem. Thank you!

This is my controller:

```
public function edit(){

            $slug=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

            $data['news_item']=$this->news_model->get_news($slug);

            $id=$data['news_item']['id'];


            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Edit a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
                {
                    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('news/edit');
                    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

                }
            else{

                $data = array(
                                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                                'text' => $this->input->post('text')
                            );

                $this->news_model->edit_news($id,$data); 
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/success');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
                }   

    }
```

These are my models, one for getting the table row, and one for updating(apparently xD):

```
public function get_news($slug= FALSE){

        if($slug === FALSE){

            $query=$this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();

        }

        $query=$this->db->get_where('news', array ('slug' => $slug));

        return $query->row_array();

    }

public function edit_news($id,$data){

        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('news',$data);

        return;
    }
```

I have debugged (if you could call it that) the controller and the models, and checked all the important values by printing them or echoing them out, and those are all in order.

Nothing wrong in my opinion with my forms or anything. It all seems to be working fine until the actuall update is called (

```
$this->db->where('id',$id); 
$this->db->update('news',$data);
```

).

I can't even remember what I tried on this xD Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning the update

```
return $this->db->update('news',$data);
```

Also where is your input for the id variable?

maybe do

```
$this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'))
```

So it looks like

```
$this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
return $this->db->update('news',$data);
```

But just try returning first.

**PART 2 from comments on how to create a update function**

```
public function edit_news($id,$data){

 $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));


  $data = array('title' => $this->input->post('title'),
              'slug' => $slug,
              'body' => $this->input->post('body')

                );

              $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));

              return $this->db->update('posts',$data);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I tried that before, no result. My id is set as auto_increment so anytime I create a something new it sets itself automatically. I have echoed it out, it's definitely there before being used by the update() function.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It worked when I added the 'id' input!! So, it does work, but since the client wouldnt' be familiar with the id, how would I pass it into the function not using the form?

Comment: I am not really sure I understand what you are asking, normally if you are on the (post) the id function should automatically be predefined and should need no action from the user, Only just clicking the edit button to call the edit function.Please give me further clarification if you need a example of this. Also if my answer worked please mark it correct so I can get credit.

Comment: I gave a example above on how I normally pass data for a update function

Comment: That's exactly what I think as well. I don't want the user to have to enter the id of the data that is being edited. I want it to be "known" or "saved" just by entering the news/edit page. Let me explain...

Comment: I extract the "slug" form the URL, and then by it's slug I pull the table row in question and then i can save it's 'id' in my $id variable. I do that at the start of the controller code. Now, I have troubleshooted a bit, and I foound that when I submit the form, my table row's "slug" dissaperas because the $slug variable is being refreshed and become "edit", not say "news-10" for example. Because of that, I cannot extract the 'id', and there is the main problem.

Comment: And thank you very much for the input, I would just like to get this sorted out before I do the correct marking. If we don't solve this, I will mark it correct nonetheless because you have been very helpful for my troubleshooting!

Comment: First have you seen the example of what I posted above just now? also if that has not worked, Try not passing the variables in the method of edit_news. Remove the $id variable and $data variable and just leave it as  edit_news(), because if you are going to use a slug variable you dont need to pass the $id variable on edit since it will be grabbed from the database.

Comment: Yes I have seen it, sorry for not mentioning it. However, I have solved the problem! I managed to get the 'id' pushed into the header of the form page 'edit.php', and there   I written it directly into the 'id' textarea to be submited when the button is pressed. That solves the problem, and I have used your example off passing data so I will ofcourse give you a correct mark!!! I cannot thank you enough, it's very gratifying to finally solve this problem. Am a bit ashamed to say, but it took me about 8 hours to find the issue. Cheers!!!!!